# Get max data for every day in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with daily data by hour. I want to get a table with only one row per day. That row should have the max value for the column AforoTotal.

This is a part of the table, containing the records of three days.

| FechaHora | Fecha | Hora | AforoTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-13T16:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 16:00:00 | 4532 |
| 2022-01-13T15:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 15:00:00 | 4419 |
| 2022-01-13T14:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 14:00:00 | 4181 |
| 2022-01-13T13:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 13:00:00 | 3914 |
| 2022-01-13T12:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 12:00:00 | 3694 |
| 2022-01-13T11:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 11:00:00 | 3268 |
| 2022-01-13T10:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 10:00:00 | 2869 |
| 2022-01-13T09:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 09:00:00 | 2065 |
| 2022-01-13T08:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 08:00:00 | 1308 |
| 2022-01-13T07:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 07:00:00 | 730 |
| 2022-01-13T06:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 06:00:00 | 251 |
| 2022-01-13T05:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 05:00:00 | 95 |
| 2022-01-13T04:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 04:00:00 | 44 |
| 2022-01-13T03:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 03:00:00 | 35 |
| 2022-01-13T02:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 02:00:00 | 28 |
| 2022-01-13T01:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 01:00:00 | 6 |
| 2022-01-13T00:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 00:00:00 | -18 |
| 2022-01-12T23:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 23:00:00 | 1800 |
| 2022-01-12T22:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 22:00:00 | 2042 |
| 2022-01-12T21:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 21:00:00 | 2358 |
| 2022-01-12T20:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 20:00:00 | 2827 |
| 2022-01-12T19:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 19:00:00 | 3681 |
| 2022-01-12T18:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 18:00:00 | 4306 |
| 2022-01-12T17:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 17:00:00 | 4377 |
| 2022-01-12T16:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 16:00:00 | 4428 |
| 2022-01-12T15:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 15:00:00 | 4424 |
| 2022-01-12T14:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 14:00:00 | 4010 |
| 2022-01-12T13:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 13:00:00 | 3826 |
| 2022-01-12T12:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 12:00:00 | 3582 |
| 2022-01-12T11:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 11:00:00 | 3323 |
| 2022-01-12T10:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 10:00:00 | 2805 |
| 2022-01-12T09:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 09:00:00 | 2159 |
| 2022-01-12T08:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 08:00:00 | 1378 |
| 2022-01-12T07:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 07:00:00 | 790 |
| 2022-01-12T06:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 06:00:00 | 317 |
| 2022-01-12T05:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 05:00:00 | 160 |
| 2022-01-12T04:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 04:00:00 | 106 |
| 2022-01-12T03:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 03:00:00 | 95 |
| 2022-01-12T02:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 02:00:00 | 86 |
| 2022-01-12T01:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 01:00:00 | 39 |
| 2022-01-12T00:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 2022-01-11T23:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 23:00:00 | 2032 |
| 2022-01-11T22:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 22:00:00 | 2109 |
| 2022-01-11T21:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 21:00:00 | 2362 |
| 2022-01-11T20:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 20:00:00 | 2866 |
| 2022-01-11T19:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 19:00:00 | 3948 |
| 2022-01-11T18:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 18:00:00 | 4532 |
| 2022-01-11T17:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 17:00:00 | 4590 |
| 2022-01-11T16:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 16:00:00 | 4821 |
| 2022-01-11T15:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 15:00:00 | 4770 |
| 2022-01-11T14:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 14:00:00 | 4405 |
| 2022-01-11T13:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 13:00:00 | 4040 |
| 2022-01-11T12:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 12:00:00 | 3847 |
| 2022-01-11T11:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 11:00:00 | 3414 |
| 2022-01-11T10:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 10:00:00 | 2940 |
| 2022-01-11T09:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 09:00:00 | 2105 |
| 2022-01-11T08:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 08:00:00 | 1353 |
| 2022-01-11T07:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 07:00:00 | 739 |
| 2022-01-11T06:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 06:00:00 | 248 |
| 2022-01-11T05:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 05:00:00 | 91 |
| 2022-01-11T04:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 04:00:00 | 63 |
| 2022-01-11T03:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 03:00:00 | 46 |
| 2022-01-11T02:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 02:00:00 | 42 |
| 2022-01-11T01:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 01:00:00 | 18 |
| 2022-01-11T00:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 00:00:00 | 5 |

My expected result is:

| FechaHora | Fecha | Hora | AforoTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-13T16:00:00Z | 2022-01-13 | 16:00:00 | 4532 |
| 2022-01-12T16:00:00Z | 2022-01-12 | 16:00:00 | 4428 |
| 2022-01-11T17:00:00Z | 2022-01-11 | 17:00:00 | 4590 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way which is little bit costly:

It will be working when (Fetcha and max(AforoTotal)) combination is unique.

In given example, I find it is unique.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE Fecha||AforoTotal 
IN 
(SELECT Fecha||MAX( AforoTotal ) FROM your_table GROUP BY Fecha);


[Output]


  https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFzWA.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select as value 
  array_agg(t order by AforoTotal desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from your_table t
group by Fecha
```

if to apply to sample data in your question  - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks @mikhail, this actually did the job, although when I save this as a view in BigQuery and then try to use that view, I got this error `Views with value table results are currently unsupported; found type STRUCT<FechaHora TIMESTAMP, Fecha DATE, Hora TIME, ...> in view`. ¿Do you have some other approach that can be saved as a view? My final goal is to use that view as a data source in DataStudio.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your approach. This can be saved as a view in BigQuery and I can use it in DataStudio. I have not tested what happens when the combination is not unique, I will see how it behaves.

Comment: I just tested this approach with duplicated data. It gets all the rows with max value.  I can life with that. Thanks a lot!!!.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this, though I haven't tested it:

```
 SELECT LAST_VALUE(FetchaHora) OVER (Partition BY Fecha ORDER BY AforoTotal ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING), Fetcha, LAST_VALUE(Hora) OVER (Partition BY Fecha ORDER BY AforoTotal ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING), LAST_VALUE(AforoTotal) OVER (Partition BY Fecha ORDER BY AforoTotal ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AforoTotal FROM your_table
```